# The characters except English are not readable on DirectAdmin editor

Tags: html, meta-tags, title, tags

When I try to edit my idex.html I see strange characters in my atributs and tags

```
<title>&#4321;&#4304;&#4304;&#4322;&#4308;&#4321;&#4322;&#4304;&#4322;&#4317;-&#4306;&#4304;&#4315;&#4317;&#4321;&#4304;&#4328;&#4309;&#4308;&#4305;&#4312; &#4306;&#4304;&#4315;&#4317;&#4330;&#4307;&#4312;&#4321; &#4318;&#4320;&#4308;&#4322;&#4308;&#4321;&#4322;&#4312;.ge,&#4322;&#4308;&#4321;&#4322;&#4308;&#4305;&#4312;,testebi</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="áƒ¢áƒ”áƒ¡áƒ¢áƒ”áƒ‘áƒ˜, áƒ¡áƒáƒáƒ¢áƒ”áƒ¡áƒ¢áƒáƒ¢áƒ, áƒžáƒ áƒ”áƒ¢áƒ”áƒ¡áƒ¢áƒ˜, áƒ’áƒáƒ›áƒáƒªáƒ“áƒ”áƒ‘áƒ˜, áƒ¡áƒáƒáƒ¢áƒ”áƒ¡áƒ¢áƒáƒ¢áƒ áƒ’áƒáƒ›áƒáƒªáƒ“áƒ”áƒ‘áƒ˜, áƒ’áƒáƒ›áƒáƒ¡áƒáƒ¨áƒ•áƒ”áƒ‘áƒ˜ áƒ’áƒáƒ›áƒáƒªáƒ“áƒ˜áƒ¡ áƒžáƒ áƒ”áƒ¢áƒ”áƒ¡áƒ¢áƒ˜, áƒžáƒ áƒ”áƒ¢áƒ”áƒ¡áƒ¢áƒ”áƒ‘áƒ˜, pretesti, saatestato gamocda, testebi, gamosaSvebi, testi ">
```

instead of `<title>საატესტატო-გამოსაშვები გამოცდის პრეტესტი.ge,ტესტები,testebi</title>`
 what have I done wrong?
By some "site checkers" my title thich has 59 characters looks like 220 char long, but I have no problem while opening the page on a browser, when everything is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing are HTML character entities. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references):

> In SGML, **HTML** and XML documents, the logical constructs known as character data and attribute values consist of sequences of characters, in which each character can manifest directly (representing itself), or can be represented by a series of characters called a character reference, of which there are two types: a numeric character reference and a **character entity reference**.

See also: [Help:Special characters](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_characters)

Basically the browser takes the entity reference (i.e. `&#4321;`) and displays it as the character it represents: `ს`.

[Reasons why they are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436615/when-should-one-use-html-entities) (I think your cause is point #2):

- your keyboard does not support the character you need to type, e.g. many keyboards do not have em-dash or the copyright symbol.
- your editor does not support unicode (very common some years ago, but probably not today)
- you want to make it explicit in the source what is happening, e.g. the   code is more clear than the corresponding whitespace character.
- when you need to escape HTML special characters like >, &, or ".

Answer (score 0):

use MANUAL CHARACTER replacing function  - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Ln51WxqR  ( i was unable to paste that function here, because the SPECIAL CHARS are being filtered by StackOverflow).

then decode like this:

```
echo INCORRECT_GEO_to_ENG('áƒ”áƒšáƒ’áƒ£áƒ¯áƒ');
```